# Не обновляются данные в контролах при изменении источника привязки

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Небольшое WPF MVVM приложение для поиска и отображения данных из БД.
Методом `GetStartData()` извлекаются данные для отображения при запуске приложения.
В обоих DataGrid все отображается, данные связаны - все работает корректно.
Поиск осуществляется методом `GetPart(Npart)`.Получаю данные.
В отладчике вижу, что данные есть и они корректны.
Но в `dataGridMaster` данные отображаются, а в `dataGridDetail1`-нет.
Если кликнуть мышью на `dataGridMaster`, тогда и в `dataGridDetail1` появляются данные.
**Вопрос.** Как сделать чтобы в `dataGridDetail1` без кликов отображались данные ?

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="SiriusCargo_MVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SiriusCargo_MVVM.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="544.842" Width="841">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel></vm:MainWindowViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="vsmaster"  Source="{Binding Parts}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="vsdetail1" Source="{Binding PARTIES_V1, Source={StaticResource vsmaster}}" />
    </Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="0,0,2,1" >
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridMaster" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vsmaster}}"  Margin="0,10,346,384" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="pART_NUMBERColumn" Binding="{Binding PART_NUMBER}" Header="PART NUMBER" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="oWNERColumn" Binding="{Binding OWNER}" Header="OWNER" Width="350"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridDetail1" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vsdetail1}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                  Margin="0,149,346,215" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="pARTIES_NUMBERColumn" Binding="{Binding PARTIES_NUMBER}" Header="PARTIES NUMBER" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="gOODSColumn" Binding="{Binding GOODS}" Header="GOODS" Width="250"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="723,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding FindPart}"/>
        <TextBox Name="tbFind" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="509,12,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=Npart, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Npart {get; set;} 

    private ObservableCollection<PartsView> _parts;
    public ObservableCollection<PartsView> Parts
    {
        get
        {
            return _parts;
        }
        set 
        {
            _parts = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Parts");
        }
    }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _parts = PartsRepository.GetStartData();
    }

    RelayCommand _findPartCommand;
    public ICommand FindPart
    {
        get
        {
            if ( _findPartCommand == null)
                 _findPartCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteFindPartCommand, CanExecuteFindPartCommand);
            return _findPartCommand;
        }
    }
    public void ExecuteFindPartCommand(object parameter)
    {
        _parts = PartsRepository.GetPart(Npart);
    }

    public bool CanExecuteFindPartCommand(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Model

```
public PartsView()
{
    PARTIES_V1 = new List<PARTIES_V1>();
}

public int ID { get; set; }

public string PART_NUMBER { get; set; }

public string OWNER { get; set; }

public int? PRICE_ID { get; set; }

public List<PARTIES_V1> PARTIES_V1 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Вы выложили простыню кода. Если вы попробуете упростить её до минимального примера, вы увеличите шансы на то, что специалисту будет не лень прочитать её.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PARTIES_V1` - надо протаскивать в Модель отображения и дергать `OnPropertyChanged` - а то вьюха-то и не знает, что там обновилось всё. Да и в `ObservableCollection` - нужно, особенно если там еще что-то добавляться будет. `Model` сама по себе не обеспечивает инфраструктуру для Binding'a - всё это надо делать через `ModelView`.

Comment: В смысле PARTIES_V1 тоже объявить как свойство VM?

Comment: Да, по сути надо писать обертку вокруг `PartsView` - скажем, `PartsViewModel` и реализовывать у всех свойств для биндинга `OnPropertyChanged`. Если уж совсем по MVVM угареть, то для каждой модели пишется своя MV, которая используется в MV окон(страниц).